# Como criar um efeito mouse-over em uma imagem e posiciona-lo onde quero?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3, div, css-hover

Estou querendo replicar um efeito de `mouse over` mas o que consegui até agora está meio bugado, a linha com o efeito está passando de um lado até o outro, e não está somente no comprimento do texto, que é o que quero, não sei como fazer para posicionar esse `div` com link dentro na parte inferior da imagem, assim como na página do oscar em *BEST PICTURE*.

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Código HTML:

```
<img style="margin-top:50px;" src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg" alt="" />
<div class="button--border-rotated"><h1><a>text here</a></h1></div>
```

CSS:

```
div.button--border-rotated {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: -170px;
}

div.button--border-rotated:hover, img:hover + div {
    display: block;
}






.button--border-rotated {
    border: none;
    position: relative;
}

a, a:active, a:focus, a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

a {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.button--border-rotated:before {
    top: 0;
}

.button--border-rotated:after, .button--border-rotated:before {
    transition: top .3s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #bfa267;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

.button--border-rotated:after, .button--border-rotated:hover:before {
    top: 100%;
}

.button--border-rotated:after, .button--border-rotated:before {
    transition: top .3s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #bfa267;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

*, :after, :before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Aqui está o link do [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6k2Lhaje/188/), pois o código `Bootstrap v3.3.6` é longo e não coube na pergunta.
Aqui a página do [oscar](http://oscar.go.com/nominees/best-picture) como referencia, note que ao passar o mouse, aparecem 2 links com efeito, é isso estou tentando fazer.

Comment: Dei mais uma modificada no codigo, para deixar mais parecido com o teu exemplo. Se te ajudou, marque a resposta como correta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criei uma *div* pai para o conteúdo e deixei o texto como `position absolute` e com `bottom 0`.

https://jsfiddle.net/6k2Lhaje/191/